# Key not found in dictionary when creating N:N relationship

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Using D365 (v 1710). I created a new custom entity, and am now trying to create an N:N relationship to the native account entity. The N:N relationship does not create, and throws a `Given key not found in the dictionary` error.

I can create the relationship in the default solution, but I'm unable to add the relationship to my solution through `Add subcomponent`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Having the same issue. Not understand why.

One option is creating a New entity with 2 lookup fields, one for each entity of the N:N relationshio I need.

Hope works for you.